# WPF вопрос по стилям в Custom Control Library

Tags: c#, wpf, style

Предположим есть библиотека custom control library
В ней описан базовый стиль для элементов, предположим следующего рода

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlLib">

<Style x:Key="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>        
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige"/>
</Style>
```

И предположим есть шаблон контрола следующего вида

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlLib">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ControlLib;component/BaseStyle.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TestControl}" x:Key="{x:Type local:TestControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TestControl}">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                                 Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Строка1"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                   Text="Строка2"/>
                    </Grid>                        
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Так вот вопрос можно ли как-то применить стиль для TexBox автоматом или надо стиль для TextBox указывать явно:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxBaseStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige"/>
</Style>
```

и для TextBox писать

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Style="{StaticResource TextBoxBaseStyle}"/>
```

Comment: `x:Key` уберите и будет вам автоматом ставить на все подходящие под `TargetType` элементы.

Comment: EvgeniyZ, пробовал, не работает так

Comment: Ну хорошо, а вы подключили хотяб эту библиотеку к вашему WPF проекту? Задали в ресурсах ссылку на ваш стиль? Сделал сейчас тестовый проект с библиотекой с [одним словарем стилей](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0w10.png)(то, что у вас). Подключил проект библиотеки [к основному](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qMrl.png), ну и задал в основном проекте (в `App.xaml`) [строку подключения словаря](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaYim.png). Все, теперь у меня все `TextBox` имеют указанный [стиль из библиотеки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKSZb.png).

Comment: Я пытаюсь заюзать стиль внутри ControlLibrary. Т.е. словарь и шаблон контрола находятся внутри библиотеки. Которая потом уже будет подключаться к аппликейшену.